# Invoking a method asynchronously and/or on its own thread to increase performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure

My question is involving a web api I created using asp.net/c# and is deployed to an Azure server. The API basically gets a requests to process an image with some text printed over it.

I have a method that is called once a get request is received. In english, the method does some setup, then downloads the proper image requested from Azure blob storage, then does the drawing.

```
public HttpResponseMessage process(string image){

DoSomeSetup();  

DownloadFromBlob(image);

return DrawTextOnImage();
}
```

My problem is that downloading from the Azure blob takes the longest time out of all the operations, usually 2-3 seconds. I figure that it would be much more efficient if I could download the image WHILE setup is occurring, in order to save time.

```
public HttpResponseMessage process(string image){

startDownloadingImageFromBlob(image);

DoSomeSetup();

EnsureImageDownloadFinished();

return DrawTextOnImage();
}
```

I am under the impression that simply calling

```
Bitmap templateImage = DownloadImageFromUrl(BLOB_STORAGE_TEMPLATES_BASE_URL)
```

at the top of the method will wait for the download to complete before moving onto the setup. Is there a way that I can get the download to happen at the same time as setup, and then (if necessary) wait for it to finish before drawing?

Comment: Unless `DoSomeSetup()` is also IO bound or particularly CPU intensive, chances are you will actually see a (imperceivable) performance decrease by trying to to the download asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** use `Wait` or `Task.Run` on ASP.NET.

Since a download is an I/O-based operation, an asynchronous approach makes the most sense. The *first* thing to do is identify which APIs are being called by `DownloadFromBlob`, change them to their asynchronous equivalents, and call them using `await`. Then allow `async` to grow from there (the compiler will guide you). Eventually, you'll end up with something like:

```
async Task<Bitmap> DownloadFromBlobAsync(string image);
```

And at this point, you can start the download by invoking (but *not* `await`ing) the method, and then `await` the task after your setup is done:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> process(string image)
{
  var task = DownloadFromBlobAsync(image);
  var setupData = DoSomeSetup();
  var image = await task;
  return DrawTextOnImage(image, setupData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a task to execute in parallel then wait for the task to complete before continuing.  Something like this:

```
// using System.Threading.Tasks;
public HttpResponseMessage process(string image) {

   var downloadTask = Task.Run(() => {
       DownloadFromBlob(image);
    });

   DoSomeSetup();  

   downloadTask.Wait();

   return DrawTextOnImage();
}
```

Reference: [MSDN Task Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. I will do some performance testing and see if this works as expected. If it does I will report back and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: but downloading is an IO operation. isn't there an asynchronous download method that does not need another extra thread?

Comment: OP is likely not experienced enough to see trolling attempt with call to .Wait on a task in Asp.net...

Comment: ^ apparently not.. care to explain?

Comment: Take a look at the async methods in HttpClient.  Good example here:  https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: My understanding is that it's not a good idea to use `Task.Run` in an ASP.NET application...at least not for I/O-bound operations. In other words, what René states.

Comment: Assuming there is actually something to be gained by doing the `DownloadByBlob` asynchronously, the `process` method itself should be marked as `async Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and the `DownloadFromBlob` should also be refactored to return a task, and then invoked using `await`.